# How to use woocommerce login on a page form then redirect user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**The Issue:**
I am trying to make a page on my site accessible to people who log in only, I have successfully achieved the is logged in show this else show the woocommerce login / register portion. I have added the code that I used for this below in the second code box.

My problem is after they log in sending them back to the page and only in this instance. For example the page is called free stuff and normally the woocommerce customer is sent to my account after logging in , instead in this singular instance when logging in from this page, I would like them to remain on the page by redirecting them to the same page, almost a refresh I guess but this time the state is logged on so they will see the content, and not the sign in form.

**What I have done:**
I have tested the logged in state manually without the redirect and it all works, as far as the content locking aspect.

I read another post about functions.php getting run too early to know what page it is , but I am not sure what this means for my situation, and how to go about accomplishing this.

with some noodling I have managed to cause all logins to redirect to this page, but that is not what is intended.

I find that when using the following code it does not seem to work,  It almost seems like it is not passing in the redirect during the if is_page('free-stuff') check.  SO after all of that here is the code I am using:

```
function wc_freestuff_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
if(is_page( 'free-stuff' )){
$redirect = 'http://www.example.com/free-stuff/';
 }
return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect',
'wc_freestuff_user_redirect',10,2);
```

Can anyone help me sort out what I may be doing wrong or how to fix this? The code is in the child themes functions.php file.

I thought it may be helpful to show how I implemented the forms. Also on the page in question I added the field of protected and set it as yes to trigger the below function

```
function restrict_page_content($content) {
if( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'protected', true ) == 'yes' && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        //consider moving this below into a page template and calling the page template instead 
    return 'YOU MUST BE LOGGED IN TO VIEW THIS CONTENT <br/ > [woocommerce_my_account]';

}
else {
    return $content;
}
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'restrict_page_content' );
```

Just to clarify this is also in the functions.php of the child theme